# Read text from txt file and split it

Tags: c#

How to read and split text in separated column?
In a file It contains this text given below.

```
[HRData]
97  0   0   99  0   50 
97  0   0   99  0   50
97  0   0   99  0   50
```

**code**

```
bool HRData = false;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!HRData)     
        {
            if (line == "[HRData]")
            {
                HRData = true;
                continue;
            } 

            string[] columns = line.Split('\t');
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(columns);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

Split string should be in separate column in `DataGridView`

```
|97|0|0|99|50|
|97|0|0|99|50|
|97|0|0|99|50|
```

Comment: i think there should be line.Split(" ");

Comment: Now please also show the expected output as a formatted table. Apart from the additional line breaks, I can't see how splitting by `" "` would not  solve this

Comment: When the input file is tab delimited, (which I can get by copying the raw input from editing your post) then your code works, so the issue is what happens between your array of strings called `columns` and the setup in your data grid view. Please confirm that the array of columns has 6 elements, because it does when I run your original code with tab delimited input

Answer (score 1):

Your text input is delimited by *spaces* not *tabs*, so as pointed out by @bhavya in the comments, you need to change the argument passed through to the `Split` function to `line.Split(" ");`:

```
bool HRData = false;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!HRData)
        {
            if (line == "[HRData]")
            {
                HRData = true;
                continue;
            }         
            string[] columns = line.Split(" ");

            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(columns);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows whole text file data only on first column

Comment: When I cut'n'paste from this post, into my VS, its is space delimited, which makes sense because you have pasted it here, if there is more data, you should post it, or use a binary editor to inspect the file to identify the actual delimiter to use. (In VS, File => Open => then once you have located you file, change the open split button to _Open With_ and select the binary editor.)

Answer (score 0):

- Extending original answer- To get exact split charater for your file you will have to share sample text file data so we can suggest the split logic
- As per current logic you are setting HRData bool flag true when [HRData] text is found in a line, this will cause next ReadLine() iteration in while loop to not split as you are negating the flag in IF, "if (!HRData)"
- And your main query as I understood is you need to have splitted data, each word/string in separate column, but you are adding Rows as single column array hence all data is in first column
- You can refer below and use Datatable to first add columns from header row or by statically hard-coding columns, then add each row using split data then set DataTable as source for GridView
- Please note I have written code in VS 2017 but haven't run it to test its working
- Edit- Modified code as per updated sample data in original question

  ```
           DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
           using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
           {
               string line = string.Empty;
               //Decide how many maximum columns/splits file will have or calculate max columns separately first by looping through file lines
               int index = -1;
               dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", Type.GetType("String")));
               dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", Type.GetType("String")));
               dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", Type.GetType("String")));
               dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", Type.GetType("String")));
               dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column5", Type.GetType("String")));
               dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column6", Type.GetType("String")));
               while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
               {
                   index++;
                   //If header row is present add columns with names
                   //string[] columns = null;
                   //if (index == 0)//Header row to add as columns with names
                   //{
                   //    columns = line.Split(' ');
                   //    foreach (var colName in columns)
                   //    {
                   //        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(colName, Type.GetType("String")));
                   //    }
                   //}
                   if (line == "[HRData]" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                   {
                       continue;
                   }
                   var row = dataTable.NewRow();
                   row.ItemArray = line.Split(' ');
                   dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
               }
           }
           dataGridView2.DataSource = dataTable;
  ```

Comment: what is dt referring to?

Comment: Corrected it to correct variable name dataTable